# Código entra em loop infinito

Tags: c, loop

Por que este código esta em *loop* infinito?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int i;
float salario[10],  valorDataBase, salarioReajustado[10];

printf("Informe o percentual  de reajuste da data-base: \n");
scanf("%f",  &valorDataBase);


    for (i=0 ; i<10 ;  i=i++)
    {
        printf("Informe o seu salario atual: \n");
        scanf("%f", &salario[i]);
    }
    //Impressão da lista de  dados do vetor salario reajustado
    for (i=0 ; i<10 ;  i=i++)
    {
        salarioReajustado[i] = salario[i] + salario[i]*valorDataBase/100;
        printf("Seu salario reajustado sera %f \n",salarioReajustado[i]);
    }

getch();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: `i=i++` deve ser apenas `i++`

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 6):

E eu pergunto, por que está incrementando a variável `i` e atribuindo a ela mesma? Isto é comportamento indefinido. Se só incrementar funciona, afinal é o correto. Deve ter copiado de forma equivocada de algum lugar. De qualquer forma o ideal é nunca copiar nada, é entender como aquilo funciona para usar de forma adequada. Simplificando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float salario[10], valorDataBase;
    printf("Informe o percentual  de reajuste da data-base: \n");
    scanf("%f", &valorDataBase);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Informe o seu salario atual:\n");
        scanf("%f", &salario[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("Seu salario reajustado sera %f\n", salario[i] + salario[i] * valorDataBase / 100);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HKOSE6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mxypbprh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/UndefinedBehaviorIncrement.c).

Dica final, em casos reais [valores monetários não podem ser do tipo `float`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Comment: Só para complementar, `i = i++` primeiro atribui e depois incrementa, por conta disso a variável `i` sempre é `0`, se fizesse dessa forma `i = ++i` funcionaria, porque primeiro incrementaria e depois atribuiria.